# DocuSign JWT Authentication Fails in Docker container using python sdk

Tags: python, docker, docusignapi

I'm using the DocuSign python sdk to send envelopes and JWT authentication. Everything works fine on my MAC. I am then trying to run same app in Docker container and it fails with exception when requesting the JWT token from DocuSign server with "no_valid_keys_or_signatures". All of the security id info seems to be correct, client Id, private key, ds_impersonated_user_id and authorization_server: account-d.docusign.com

What am I missing?

```
2020-07-15 16:27:51,363 - ERROR - fail to get jwt toekn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/app/utils/docusign.py", line 366, in _jwt_auth
    expires_in=3600
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docusign_esign/client/api_client.py", line 694, in request_jwt_user_token
    {"assertion": token, "grant_type": OAuth.GRANT_TYPE_JWT}))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docusign_esign/client/api_client.py", line 399, in request
    body=body)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docusign_esign/client/api_response.py", line 235, in POST
    body=body)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docusign_esign/client/api_response.py", line 191, in request
    raise ApiException(http_resp=r)
docusign_esign.client.api_exception.ApiException: (400)
Reason: Bad Request
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Expires': '-1', 'Server': 'Microsoft-IIS/8.5', 'X-AspNetMvc-Version': '5.2', 'X-DocuSign-TraceToken': '9a5577d0-1229-469e-b93d-54a20ae3e90b', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload, max-age=15768000', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block; report=/client-errors/xss', 'X-DocuSign-Node': 'SE2DFE3', 'Date': 'Wed, 15 Jul 2020 16:27:50 GMT', 'Content-Length': '75'})
HTTP response body: b'{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"no_valid_keys_or_signatures"}'
```

Comment: how do you store the configuration? you need three things - IK, RSA Key and the User's ID (GUID)

Comment: The configuration is stored in a combination of environ variables and private key file. I am using the same code as DocuSign github repo "code-examples-python". The code works fine outside of Docker container. I added print statements to show myself the values are being loaded. I'm guessing that maybe things are not being encoded before being sent?

Comment: env variables in the docker container maybe not configured correctly?

Comment: if the RSA Key (private.key) file is stored in the box, make sure Docker can access it. Same for the configuration file. I've seen a situation where it has to be mounted or something for Docker to see it

Comment: as I wrote I print the variables to the console before the call. So I know the values are being loaded. The private key is also printed. Those are very good suggestions, and I have verfied the values. My next step is to try and find a way to monitor the api network calls.

Comment: do you run the docker on your dev box or on some remote server? can you try AWS docker service or something similar?

Comment: I have run the docker containers on multiple systems. But I have not tried AWS. 3 separate computers so far.

Comment: The error, message, where is it coming from? it has a typo and I wonder if it's in your code or this is coming from DocuSign? ("ERROR - fail to get jwt toekn" instead of "ERROR - fail to get jwt token")

Comment: That was from my exception logging

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special you need to do to use JWT authentication for DocuSign using Docker or AWS.
We do that in some of our sample apps, like https://myhr.sampleapps.docusign.com/ when you log in using the "test account" which is hardcoded.

The things to keep in mind to get JWT working are:

1. Make sure you use the correct private key part of the RSA keypair *exactly* as it was given to you including end of lines etc.
2. Double check the account Id, the user ID and that all the URLs point to the developer env (account-d.docusign.com)
3. Make sure you got consent and that it includes the *impersonation* scope.

Those should all be double checked, but I also suggest you try our Python quickstart that configures it all for you automagically - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/